# How do I set the browser language in Cucumber / Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'd like a different language to be displayed depending on the browser language and naturally I'd like to test to make sure it's working properly. I'm using Cucumber and Capybara, Gem versions 1.0.6 and 1.1.1 respectively.

I've found a few suggestions on the web, but none that work so far. I've tried the following (individually) without success.

```
page.driver.language = language
header "Accept-Language", language
page.driver.header 'Accept-Language', language
```

Where language is set to either "en" or "fr".

Can anyone help? Thanks, Graeme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it!

I had the right line, the problem was elsewhere.

```
page.driver.header 'Accept-Language', language
```

This works fine, the problem was that my Scenario was as follows.

```
Scenario:
  Given I am an anonymous user
  And the browser language is fr
  Then I should see "Bonjour"
```

And it should have been

```
Scenario:
  Given the browser language is fr
  And I am an anonymous user
  Then I should see "Bonjour"
```

The 'I am an anonymous user' step was just doing a sign out first. It would seem that the browser language must be set before any other steps are taken which use the browser.

Answer (score 2):

With [poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist):

```
page.driver.add_headers('Accept-Language' => 'fr')
```

More details: https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#manipulating-request-headers

Answer (score 1):

What Capybara driver are you using? This works for Mechanize:

```
When /^I set my browser language to French$/ do
    page.driver.agent.request_headers['Accept-Language'] = 'fr'
end
```

Comment: I haven't specifically set a driver to use, so whatever the default Capybara driver is. Would I get better results by setting something specific? Thanks.

Comment: You'll be using rack-test then. If the above doesn't work then try this: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/320

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for the link, but I'm still a bit lost as to what I put where to be able to set the language on the fly. Apologies for being a bit dense! Cheers, Graeme